# Exclude entire directory with whitespace in name

Tags: python, flake8, linter

I have a directory called "Old stuff" that I want `flake8` to not lint code in this directory.

What is the correct syntax to exclude it?

I looked at the [documentation](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html) for configuring flake8 but did not find what I wanted.

I tried in my `.flake8` file:

```
[flake8]
max-line-length = 99
exclude =
    # Don't check the Old directories
    # Attempt 1
    Old\ stuff
    # Attempt 2
    "Old stuff"
    # Attempt 3
    /Old stuff/
    # Attempt 4
    ./Old stuff/
    # Attempt 5
    /Old\ stuff/
```

None of those syntax works.

Same problem when trying to exclude on the command line:

```
flake8 --exclude=Old\ stuff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `flake8` to ignore the directory with the whitespace, this syntax works:

```
[flake8]
max-line-length = 99
exclude =
    # Don't check the Old directories
    Old*stuff
```

For the command line:

```
flake8 --exclude=Old*stuff
```